# Criterion for deducing connectedness of level set of a smooth map

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Suppose that $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open and suppose that $f: U\to \mathbb R$ is smooth. Define $M_c= f^{-1}(c)$. The question is: is $M_c$ connected?

Here is an example where $M_c$ is connected for a particular $c$ but not connected for some other values of $c$:

$n=2, f(x,y)= x^2-y^2$. In this case, $M_0=$ pair of straight lines passing through the origin and therefore $M_0$ is connected. But $M_1=\{(x,y): x^2-y^2=1\}$ is not connected.

It suggests that there should be some restriction on $c$ but I’m not sure how to generalise this. Any suggestions on this are welcome. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is unlikely to generalise this result since we can find many easy
examples that a level set is not connected. In general, the preimage of a connected set under a continuous
map is not connected. Although it is not the same case, it provides a reason
the preimage of a point set under a continuous/smooth map may not be connected.

Here is an example $M_c$ is not connected though $U$ is open connected.

Consider $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $f(x)=\sin(x)$.

Then $M_c= f^{-1}(c)$ is not connected for all $c\in [0,1]$.

Rather than restrict  c, we can restrict $U$ to a smaller open subset such that
$M_c$ is connected for some $c$, and even more, restrict $U$ such that f is injective,
though this is not a result you want.

In general, $M_c= f^{-1}(c)$ may contain more than one connected components, therefore
$M_c$ is not connected.

In your example, consider $U=\mathbb R$, $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$,
and $f(x,y)= x^2-y^2$.

For $c\ge 0$, let $M_c=\{(x,y): x^2-y^2=c\}$, $M_{c,1}=M_c\cap \{x\ge0\}$ and $M_{c,2}=M_c\cap \{x\le0\}$.

It is known that $M_{c,1}$ and $M_{c,2}$ are connected. When $c> 0$, $M_{c,1}$ and $M_{c,2}$ are disjoint, also connected components of $M_c$, therefore $M_c$ is not connected. $M_{c,1}$ intersects $M_{c,2}$ only when $c=0$, and at $x=0, y=0$. Since $M_{0,1}$ and $M_{0,2}$ are connected subspaces of $M_0$ having a common point, so $M_0$ is connected.

Now if we remove the common point, that is restrict $U=R^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, then $M_c$ is not connected for all $c$.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the smoothness of $f$, you can ask the same question for each continuous $f$.

There are certainly no conditions concerning **only** the the point $c$ which can assure the connectedness of $M_c$, it is a property of the **whole** map $f : U \to \mathbb R$.

Moreover, it is not a local property of $f$, but a global one.

Assume that $M_c$ is connected and has more than one point. Pick $x_1, x_2 \in M_c$ and choose two disjoint open neighborhoods $V_i$ of $x_i$ in $M_c$. We have $V_1 \cup V_2 \ne M_c$ since $M_c$ is connected. Then $C = M_c \setminus (V_1 \cup V_2)$ is closed in $M_c$, thus closed in $U$ and $U' = U \setminus C$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. The restriction $f' : U' \to \mathbb R$ of $f$ has a non-connected fiber $(f')^{-1}(c) = V_1 \cup V_2$, but locally it has the same properties as $f$.